# Calling Models in Module in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, zend-loader

I have a structure that is

```
application
application/modules
application/modules/default
application/modules/default/models
application/modules/admin
application/modules/admin/models
```

When calling controllers in admin I understand they must be named like `Admin_TestController`. This works fine, but my models in my admin module don't seem to be able to load. I have tried naming them and the files in all kinds of ways but it just doesn't seem to want to be able to load them. How should I name the file and model class in a module to be able to use it? I use autoloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fatmuemoo states the bootstrap for the module should extend Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap also you should include

```
resources.modules[] =
```

In your config. This is in the [docs for Zend_Application_Resource_Modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html)

Comment: I hade missed adding this to my configuration... Thanx ;)

Comment: @bangline : Out of curiosity, would like to confirm, on how this impacts the performance of the project, does this configuration makes to include all the models on initialization or it just provides the mechanism for autoloading the resources?

Answer (score 4):

What do your bootstrap files look like? That is the most import part of problem.

It is very important (in order for the namespaces to autoload) that you you have a bootstrap in each module (located @ application/modules/admin/bootstrap.php) that should contain, at the very least:

```
class Reports_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
```

Notice that it extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap. This does the heavy lifting of registering the namespaces for the MVC of the module.

Comment: Often missed but this was not my problem... I had already remembered this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to include a bootstrap class that extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap for the modules you want to use.  Check [this forum post about a similar issue](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/core-infrastructure-19/zend_application_module_autoloader-cannot-find-my-models-4240.html) to see if it helps point you in the right way.  Seems you may need more than one to load separate modules.